# Is it more efficient to use a texture atlas when using Javascript Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, gpu, textures

Generally with game programming it's more efficient to use spritesheets / texture atlases when drawing multiple different objects because instead of making the GPU switch textures and perform costly context switches, you can stay on the same texture and just draw the relevant object from a rectangular clipped region of the large texture image.

However, does this also apply to the high-level Javascript Canvas API? It may seem intuitive that it does, but it is a high-level API, so perhaps this does not occur? For example, maybe there's an implicit context switch after every `ctx.drawImage` call. Or maybe the performance difference is negligible due to overhead.

Has anyone experimented with this? If so, is there much of a performance overhead with drawing multiple objects, each from their own separate Image, versus packing all the textures into a single spritesheet and drawing from there?

Is there a significant performance difference? Because having multiple images is easier to code, so I don't want to bother setting up texture atlassing if there is not much of a performance benefit to it.

Comment: Highly dependent on the Browser / OS / Hardware / Drivers the client has. Best to limit the total number of state changes. `ctx.drawImage(A, 0, 0);  tx.drawImage(B, 0, 0); ` will be just as fast as `ctx.drawImage(C, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100); tx.drawImage(C, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100); ` (on same device where `A`, `B` are two images and `C` is a sprite sheet of the two images) as long as either the two sprite images or one sprite sheet fit in GPU RAM